# Nodejs Server Hostname

Tags: http, node.js, express

Ok, so it seems pretty easy in Node.js to get the hostname of the request being made to my server:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.headers.host);
});
```

Is there an easy way to determine the hostname of my actual http server? For example, my server is running at the address `http://localhost:3000` - can I programatically determine this address? I am using expressjs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes you can using the;

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server  = require('http').createServer(app);

server.listen(3000, function(err) {
        console.log(err, server.address());
});
```

should print

```
{ address: '0.0.0.0', family: 'IPv4', port: 3000 }
```

you can also retreive the hostname for the os by the following;

```
require('os').hostname();
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the response and the help! If I do "host localhost" in terminal I get the response "localhost has address 127.0.0.1", but server.address() produces "0.0.0.0". Is there a reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: I'm not sure why it resolves to 0.0.0.0, I had a problem when trying to use the address() method to listen to a bound tcp socket as windows would fire an error for the 0.0.0.0 ip address, I had to map 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1

0.0.0.0 can occur for a lot of reasons, it can mean all interfaces on a machine, it can also mean no ip is associated with a machine as well as a few other things as well from the short research I've done on it.

Comment: `localhost` for me comes as `{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 5000 }`.

Comment: @ptf I have just discovered the same, do you have knowledge if this occurs only on `localhost`?

Comment: @Tarekis I don't know, and I'm not in front of a computer right now :)

Comment: @ptf Too bad i don't have a live server at the moment .. i'll see eventually :)

Comment: I only have app object, so I have to make object from http.createServer and I think this is not modular.

Comment: The discrepancy is because the server is listening on `0.0.0.0` which is the IPv4 version of "listen on every available address".  So the server is actually listening to that port on every address the machine has.  You can connect to it via `127.0.0.1`, but it doesn't report that because you can also connect to it via whatever other IP addresses the machine has.