# Express: How do you get the hostname and port that an express server is listening on, WITHOUT waiting for a request

Tags: node.js, express

It's fairly straight forward to get the hostname and URL from a request that has been made to an express server. But there seems to be no obvious way to determine which URL an express server is listening on (after it has been started up, but before any requests have been sent).

How do you find out which host and port an express server is listening on? Does express even know which host and port it is listening on?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12566283/4774345

Comment: Creating an entirely new server just to get the address seems a bit heavyweight

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a new one. Presumably you've already created the server, so you can call `address()` on that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you create an server like this:

```
  var server = http.createServer(app);
```

The server instance actually contains the port and address it's listening. So you could just export it, and call `server.address()` to get the address and port.

```
  { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 3200 }
```

If you want further info about what urls are your routes are routing, try

```
  console.log(router.stack)
```

then the magic happens. :)

Comment: Creating an entirely new server just to get the address seems a bit heavyweight. Isn't this info stored directly in `express`?

Comment: You are not really listening on any port unless you run a server. no?

Comment: It's not about creating a new server. It's the server you already created to actually accept&handle the requests.  And yes, the app.js or bin/www that express generates does contain code to initialize/start your server. And that server instance there, if you export it, can be accessed any time you want so you could get all the info you need anytime.